# mayavi can not render 3d volume

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, mayavi

I tried to test the example below in jupyter notebook using mayavi to render a volume

```
from mayavi import mlab
mlab.init_notebook()
x, y, z = np.ogrid[-10:10:20j, -10:10:20j, -10:10:20j]
s = np.sin(x*y*z)/(x*y*z)
mlab.pipeline.volume(mlab.pipeline.scalar_field(s))
```

and I received the error:

```
Notebook initialized with x3d backend.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last) /Users/phan/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/formatters.pyc in __call__(self, obj)
    309             method = get_real_method(obj, self.print_method)
    310             if method is not None:
--> 311                 return method()
    312             return None
    313         else:

/Users/phan/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mayavi/tools/notebook.pyc in _repr_html_(self)
     58         return scene_to_png(scene)
     59     elif _backend == 'x3d':
---> 60         return scene_to_x3d(scene)
     61 
     62 

/Users/phan/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mayavi/tools/notebook.pyc in scene_to_x3d(scene)
     91     else:
     92         url_base = "http://www.x3dom.org/download"
---> 93     x3d_elem = _fix_x3d_header(ex.output_string)
     94     html = '''
     95     %s

/Users/phan/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mayavi/tools/notebook.pyc in _fix_x3d_header(x3d)
     70     rep += '>'
     71 
---> 72     x3d = x3d.replace(
     73         '<X3D profile="Immersive" version="3.0">',
     74         rep

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'

Out[39]: <mayavi.modules.volume.Volume at 0x132e605f0>
```

I installed Python 2.7, VTK 6.3, trait 4.6 in anaconda.

Comment: Same problem with Python 3.7, when using mayavi x3d mode (which otherwise has much faster and better visuals the ipy mode). Mesh rendering works OK, volume rendering fails with this error, apparently caused by x3d producing no output.

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed x3d? To install the extension, the method given by the mayavi doc is

```
jupyter nbextension install --py mayavi --user
```

(see http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/tips.html#using-mayavi-in-jupyter-notebooks).

This should fix the problem.

Comment: I have the same problem as the OP, and it is specific to volume rendering, other plot types work. (so at least for me it is not an extension issue)

Comment: It is another problem then. Please open a dedicated question.